# Store Json data from server to array in Angular 2

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, angular, typescript

I use nodejs server to get data from an SQL database.

I would store data in taches which is an array of Tache :

```
getTaches(): Observable<Tache[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.tachesUrl)
    .map(response => {
      this.taches = response.json().data as Tache[];

      console.log(this.taches);
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);

}
```

When I print on console this taches I get result as :

```
undefined
```

When I print response.json() I get my values :

```
Object {taches: Array(8)}
```

So I delete .data and try again, then I get another error on line 1 of the template file :

```
 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
```

here's my html file :

```
         <md-toolbar color="primary">
      <span>Taches non traitées</span>
    </md-toolbar>
        <md-card>


            <md-list   >
                      <ng-container *ngFor="let tache of this.tacheService.taches   "  >

                <md-list-item *ngIf="tache.stat == 0" (click)="onSelect(tache)" [class.selectionnee]="tache === tacheSelectionnee">{{tache.stat}}+{{tache.id}} + {{tache.name}}

                    <div *ngIf="tache === tacheSelectionnee">

                        <button md-icon-button  [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
                            <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
                        </button>
                        <md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
                            <button md-menu-item (click)="openDialog(tache)">
                                <md-icon>edit</md-icon>
                                <span>Modifier</span>
                            </button>
                            <button md-menu-item (click)="delete(tache)">
                                <md-icon>delete</md-icon>
                                <span>Supprimer</span>
                            </button>
                            <button md-menu-item (click)="save(tache)">
                                <md-icon>cached</md-icon>
                                <span>Traiter</span>
                            </button>
                        </md-menu>


                    </div>

                </md-list-item>

                </ng-container>

            </md-list>
        </md-card>
```

I would store data in taches array correctly so that I could show them as todo list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
getTaches(): Observable<Tache[]> { 
    return this.http.get(this.tachesUrl)
      .map(response => {
         this.taches = response.json().taches as Tache[];

  console.log(this.taches);
})
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

your object received from the api holds the `taches` array